# C# user defined exception not being caught

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I defined my custom exception like this:

```
[Serializable]
    public class WrongFileException : Exception
    {
        public WrongFileException()
        {

        }
        public WrongFileException(string message) : base(message)
        {

        }

        public WrongFileException(string message, Exception innerExeException) : base(message, innerExeException)
        {

        }
    }
```

I have a button that opens a file and I want to throw an exception when it's the wrong file:

```
private void PanelOpen_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog opendlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
        opendlg.DefaultExt = ".xml";
        opendlg.Filter="XML Files|*.xml";

        Nullable<bool> result = opendlg.ShowDialog();

        if (result == true)
        {
            XmlSerializer XMLSerial = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Panel>));
            FileStream fsCheck = new FileStream(opendlg.FileName, FileMode.Open);
            XmlReader reader = new XmlTextReader(fsCheck);
            fsCheck.Close();
            if (!XMLSerial.CanDeserialize(reader))
            {
                throw (new WrongFileException("Wrong data sructure for PanelList"));
            }
            try
            {
                using (FileStream fsRead = new FileStream(opendlg.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    PanelList = XMLSerial.Deserialize(fsRead) as List<Panel>;
                }
                PanelBoxListView.ItemsSource = PanelList;
                PanelBoxListView.Items.Refresh();
            }
            catch(WrongFileException q)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("WrongFileException: {0}", q.Message);
                throw;
            }
        }
        CheckForListEntries();
    }
```

Testing it trying to open with a file that won't work I get "WrongFileException was unhandled". I don't get why because I am catching the exception?

Comment: The exception has to be thrown from the `try` block in order to be caught.

Comment: Y catch-statement can only handle those exceptions that were caused by the `try`-block they relate to. Put your serializer-statements *into* the try-block and your done.

Comment: @GabrielNegut That is the answer, not a comment. If you write it as answer, I can remove mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It catches only if the exception is thrown within try block.

```
            try
            {
                if (!XMLSerial.CanDeserialize(reader))
                {
                    throw (new WrongFileException("Wrong data sructure for PanelList"));
                 }
                using (FileStream fsRead = new FileStream(opendlg.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    PanelList = XMLSerial.Deserialize(fsRead) as List<Panel>;
                }
                PanelBoxListView.ItemsSource = PanelList;
                PanelBoxListView.Items.Refresh();
            }
            catch(WrongFileException q)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("WrongFileException: {0}", q.Message);
                //throw; throw only if you handle/log it down the track
            }
```

Comment: yes re-throwing was wrong, thanks for the explanation, I got it and now it's working.

Answer (score 1):

Your `throw (new WrongFileException(...));` is ***before*** the `try` block, so the `try`-`catch` never becomes relevant.